# lightning-input-address embedded in VF page. Address lookup not working

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, bug, lightninginput, address

I have a use case to embed a lightning web component in a VF Page (in Classic) which includes a lightning-input-address component. The component includes the standard address lookup input (which searches for addresses for the user) functionality.

This component works when placed on a page in Lightning Experience. However, when embedded in a VF page via an Aura app, the search lookup component doesn't produce results when typed into. I've produced a simple version of the LWC with just the lightning-input-address component and found the same behaviour.

```
<template>
<lightning-record-edit-form 
    object-api-name="Contact">

    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">

        <lightning-input-address id="inputAddress"
                                                required
                                                show-address-lookup="true"
                                                address-label="Address"
                                                street-label="Street"
                                                city-label="City"
                                                country-label="Country"
                                                province-label="County"
                                                postal-code-label="PostCode"
        ></lightning-input-address>

    </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

There's nothing in the Javascript of the component beyond importing LightningElement and exporting the module itself (but no other code)

By my reading of the documentation, this should just work. Is there a known limitation here?

Comment: is it classic or lightning?

Comment: Hey Pranay - The VF page is used in Classic.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [lightning-input-address](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/example)

The supported experience are Lightning Experience , Lightning communities,Mobile App and StandAlone Apps.

[image]

There is no mention of classic, thus I believe it's not supported.

`lightning-input-address` even though look like standalone component it uses so many internal methods of lightning experience / one/one.app. As if not being not present in lightning container, it won't work,

Comment: You make a fair point. Slightly annoyingly, the release notes say you can embed Lightning Web Components in a VF page, but NONE of the standard web components are yet listed as supporting the Experience. It leaves us in a bind, somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address) does not specifically mention that Lightning Out is supported. Components that are supported would specifically state Lightning Out. Also, note that if you're in Spring '19, Lightning Out does not yet support any LWC at all; you'd have to test this in a Summer '19 sandbox to see which components are supported.